# SQL Find consistent failures

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table of student ID's subjects and grades

```
ID    SUBJECT   GRADE  DATE
01    math      A      23/1/2013
02    eng       C      22/2/2013
02    math      D      24/3/2012
03    social    B-     1/3/2012
03    math      E      14/5/2014
......
```

For most subjects a fail grade is C, D or E

For math a fail grade is B-, C, D or E

I want to find students who have had a run of 5 consecutive failed grades within a cycle of 15 grades. I want to be alerted immediately after 5 happen. So for example

```
A A A B C C C C C A A A A B A
```

or

```
D E E E B-   (maths)
```

After 11 passes I am not interested

```
D D D D A A A A A A A B B B B
```

I am using postgresql and am guessing that a window or aggregate function would help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to take an approach of assigning an integer to the grades, such that 0 is a fail and 1 is a pass (depending on subject of course, and preferably looked up from a table that correlates grades and subjects to passes and fails).

The problem then reduces to, "In a series of 5 integers, is the sum equal to 0?".

Something like:

```
Sum(pass_fail_integer) over (partition by student
                                 order by date
                                     rows between 4 preceding and current row)
```

If a sequence of 5 fails defines the condition that you want to be warned of, I'm not clear on the significance of the cycle of 15 grades. Possibly you'd be looking for a series of 15 integers with a sum of less than 11?

Edit: if you want to confine the search to the most recent 15 grades, then a subquery that assigns a row_number to the grades per student, in date descending order, allows you to filter for the most recent 15, in which you would then apply the above logic to determine whether there are five consecutive failures.

So the general structure of the query would be:

```
select
  distinct student
from (
  select ...
         sum(pass_fail_integer) over
           (partition by student
                order by date
            rows between 4 preceding and
                         current row) consecutive_failures
  from (
    select ...
           row_number() over (partition by student
                                    order by date desc) rn
    from   ...)
  where rn <= 15)
where consecutive_failures = 5)
```

You might leverage that inner query to also evaluate whether 5 failures have occurred in the 15 grade window, so you can eliminate early any students for which a check for 5 *consecutive* failures is not needed.

Comment: The 15 grades caveat is important as we want to monitor the student after the five failures. The sum of 15 will not work as we don't want to be flagged for:- A B D D D B B B D D A A A A A

Comment: So you don't want to be notified of 1110000011, it has to be 111000001111111? (1 being pass, 0 being fail)

Comment: Yes, we do want that as well. Basically we need to know 5 consecutive grade failures in the last 15 or less grades.

Comment: You're either looking for (i) any five consecutive failures, or (ii) any five failures in any consecutive set of 15 grades, or (iii) any five *consecutive* failures inside the set of the last 15 tests only, or (iv) any five failures inside the set of the last 15 tests only. Can you chose one of those?

Comment: (v) any five consecutive failures in the last set of grades up to and including the fifteenth most recent (a student may have between 0 and 120 grades)